# React-resizable - iframe causing resize not to stop when releasing mouse and reaching minConstraints

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-resizable](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) in my project. I have resizable box where I have set the `minConstraints` prop. My issue is that when resizing the box and reaching the `minConstraints`, after I release the mouse button, it will still keep resizing the box and make it bigger if I move the mouse in opposite direction, since it is still tracking mouse movement.

If I do the opposite, resize the box to make it bigger by holding the mouse down, after releasing the mouse the box won't be resizing since I have released the mouse. How can I fix that, and have the same behaviour when I reach the `minConstraints` as well?

This is the component:

```
function PaperComponent({ x, y, setX, setY, ...props }) {
  return (
    <Draggable
      position={{ x: x, y: y }}
      cancel={".react-resizable-handle"}
      onDrag={(e) => {
        if (e.movementX !== 0) {
          setX((prev) => prev + e.movementX);
        }
        if (e.movementY !== 0) {
          setY((prev) => prev + e.movementY);
        }
      }}
    >
      <Paper {...props} />
    </Draggable>
  );
}

const StyledDialog = withStyles({
  root: {
    pointerEvents: "none"
  },
  paper: {
    pointerEvents: "auto"
  },
  scrollPaper: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    marginRight: 20
  }
})((props) => <Dialog hideBackdrop {...props} />);

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dialog: {
    cursor: "move"
  },
  dialogContent: {
    "&:first-child": {
      padding: 10,
      background: "white"
    }
  },
  clearIcon: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: -20,
    right: -20,
    background: "white",
    zIndex: 1,
    "&:hover": {
      background: "white"
    }
  },
  paper: {
    overflowY: "visible",
    maxWidth: "none",
    maxHeight: "none"
  },
  resizable: {
    position: "relative",
    "& .react-resizable-handle": {
      position: "absolute",
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      background:
        "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDYiIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiNmZmZmZmYwMCIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iNnB4Ij48ZyBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjMwMiI+PHBhdGggZD0iTSA2IDYgTCAwIDYgTCAwIDQuMiBMIDQgNC4yIEwgNC4yIDQuMiBMIDQuMiAwIEwgNiAwIEwgNiA2IEwgNiA2IFoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAwMDAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+')",
      backgroundPosition: "bottom right",
      padding: 3,
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
      backgroundOrigin: "content-box",
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      boxSizing: "border-box",
      cursor: "se-resize"
    }
  },
  iframe: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    padding: 20
  }
});

function PDFDialog() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <StyledDialog
      open={open}
      classes={{ root: classes.dialog, paper: classes.paper }}
      PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
      aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog"
      PaperProps={{
        x: x,
        y: y,
        setX: setX,
        setY: setY
      }}
    >
      <ResizableBox
        height={520}
        width={370}
        minConstraints={[370, 520]}
        maxConstraints={[Infinity, Infinity]}
        className={classes.resizable}
        onResize={(e) => {
          if (e.movementX !== 0) {
            setX((prev) => prev + e.movementX);
          } else if (e.movementY !== 0) {
            setY((prev) => prev + e.movementY / 2);
          }
        }}
      >
        <DialogContent
          classes={{ root: classes.dialogContent }}
          id="draggable-dialog"
        >
          <IconButton
            className={classes.clearIcon}
            aria-label="Clear"
            onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
          >
            <ClearIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <iframe
            className={classes.iframe}
            src="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf"
            title="PDF test file"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
          ></iframe>
        </DialogContent>
      </ResizableBox>
    </StyledDialog>
  );
}

export default PDFDialog;
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-feynman-gybve?file=/src/PDFDialog.js:0-4077).

It seems that `iframe` is causing the problem. If I set `z-index: -1` on it, then it behaves as it should. But, then I have the problem of not being able to scroll inside the iframe. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Like the z-index fix, setting `pointerEvents: 'none'` on the iframe also seems to mitigate the issue, but it is likely to have the same no-scrolling problem. (I can't say for sure. The iframe content doesn't actually load for me in the sandbox.)

The issue seems to be that the `mouseup` event that stops the drag behavior is occurring outside the viewport (because of the iframe) so the thing tracking the drag never receives it and doesn't know to stop.

One potential solution would be to register a `mouseout` listener on `document` at the start of the drag that fires a mouseup event manually to stop the dragging.

This needs some tuning--if you drag too fast it fires prematurely--but here's a proof of concept in a [fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-resonance-o983p?file=/src/PDFDialog.js).

You might be able to fix the premature halt via a setTimeout or by seeing if you've hit the constraint limits. I haven't thought it through completely, but I think it's solvable.

```
onResize = {(e) => {
    // handler for when the mouse exits the active document (enters the iframe)
    const onMouseLeave = () => {
        // construct a mouseup event…
        const event = new MouseEvent("mouseup", { view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
        // …and dispatch it
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
        // remove the listener since we're not dragging anymore
        document.removeEventListener("mouseout", onMouseLeave);
    };
    // register the mouseleave handler above
    document.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseLeave);

    // continue with whatever else you're already doing
    if (e.movementX !== 0) {
        setX((prev) => prev + e.movementX);
    } else if (e.movementY !== 0) {
        setY((prev) => prev + e.movementY / 2);
    }
```

Afterthoughts:

1. This seems like a bug in react-draggable. If you work out a solid fix you might consider submitting a PR for it. (You might see if someone already has.)
2. Something in your app is stealing focus every time it renders, making editing in codesandbox super annoying.
3. You probably don't need to add the listener from inside the onResize handler. Might be more efficient and maintainable to handle it on mount or something. Again, I haven't really thought this through thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that iframe is causing the problem. If I set z-index: -1 on
> it, then it behaves as it should. But, then I have the problem of not
> being able to scroll inside the iframe. How can I fix that?

Since it behaves as it should as you have mentioned when adding `z-index: -1` CSS property to the `iframe`, just add that CSS property whenever you start resizing and remove it when you stop resizing and you are done!

Relevant code below:

```
function PDFDialog() {
  const [resizeInProgress, setResizeInProgress] = React.useState(false);

  const iFrameStyle = {
    zIndex: -1 // simply add this when you start the resizing process
  };

  return (
    <ResizableBox
      onResizeStart={() => setResizeInProgress(true)}
      onResizeStop={() => setResizeInProgress(false)}
    >
      <iframe
        style={resizeInProgress ? iFrameStyle : {}}
      ></iframe>
    </ResizableBox>
  )
}
```

Comment: I know, I did that. But, I thought it seems like a hack, so I am not sure if that is the best way to solve it.

Comment: You mean like a out-of-the-box built in functionality? Probably not - it would be worth posting an issue to [`Github`](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) though if you want to submit a feature request pertaining to `iframe` as child.

Comment: There is also one thing with changing the z-index that I noticed. If you start to move your mouse to minimize from the initial point, when you just opened the dialog, the mouse gets stucked to the resizable box, and you need to press the mouse again to stop resizing the box. It works fine in every other case.

Comment: I think the draggable component is causing that - the `Resizable` & `Draggable` are in conflict. Let me know what you think or if you already resolved the issue